# OpenAM issue with policies creation

Tags: java, policy, openam, subject, forgerock

we are trying openAM OpenIdentity product, but we have found a little issue.
We use the OpenAM OpenIdentity in version 14.4.2 with Tomcat 9 and Latest Version of Java JDK 8
When we trying to create a subject -- OpenAM Identity Subject
[image]

We create the subject and we insert a name for the subject and search for a group to associate to this subject
[image]

When we click on Search, the page send this error
[image]

Can you help us to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards

Comment: It would be better to provide tomcat logs for this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is creating a policy subject condition - not a subject itself. This will kick off an LDAP search for subjects within your DataStore. If it errors on search it is most likely an LDAP BIND failing.

The IdRepo logs alongside the catalina.out would be where your answer lies in terms of search failures / connection failures.